# Sorting list of strings based on multiple regex groups in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of strings of the form:

```
my_list=['i99_W_t10', 'i99_M_t11', 'i94_M_t12', 'i93_W_t2', ..., 'i14_M_t19']
```

(so always 3 fields sepparated by `_`. I would like to sort this list first by the 2nd element, then the 3rd and then the 1st. So the list above would become:

```
my_list=['i99_M_t11',  'i94_M_t12', 'i14_M_t19', 'i93_W_t2', 'i99_W_t10', ... ]
```

I know how to do this by turning the list into a pandas dataframe, splitting fields into columns, sorting them, and returning the sorted list. But perhaps there is a more elegant way done directly on the list instead of having to go for dataframes?

Comment: you can use sorted, split functions with making a class which can use spilt and define a data member of list by splitting _ , then make use of sorted function.

Comment: @GautamJangid good idea, please consider adding as an answer! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split each string on `'_'` and then use [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to extract items from each list in your particular order

```
from operator import itemgetter
my_list=['i99_W_t10', 'i99_M_t11', 'i94_M_t12', 'i93_W_t2','i14_M_t19']
key_func = lambda x: itemgetter(1, 2, 0)(x.split('_'))
sorted(my_list, key=key_func)
# ['i99_M_t11', 'i94_M_t12', 'i14_M_t19', 'i99_W_t10', 'i93_W_t2']
```

Example of itemgetter in action

```
itemgetter(1, 2, 0)(['a', 'b', 'c'])
# ('b', 'c', 'a')

itemgetter(2, 1, 0)(['a', 'b', 'c'])
# ('c', 'b', 'a')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this...

```
my_list = ['i99_W_t10', 'i99_M_t11', 'i94_M_t12', 'i93_W_t2', 'i14_M_t19']
# print(my_list)

def getValuesFromListItem(n):
    global my_list
    mvl = []
    for i in my_list:
        mvl += [i.split("_")[n]]
    return mvl

def getListItemFromValue(val, n):
    res = ""
    global my_list
    k = 0
    for i in my_list:
        l = i.split("_")
        if l[n] == val:
            res = i
            del my_list[k]
            break
        k += 1
    return res

l1 = getValuesFromListItem(1)
l2 = sorted(l1)
my_list2 = []
for i in l2:
    my_list2.append(getListItemFromValue(i, 1))

my_list = my_list2
my_list2 = []

l1 = getValuesFromListItem(2)
l2 = sorted(l1)
for i in l2:
    my_list2.append(getListItemFromValue(i, 2))

my_list = my_list2
my_list2 = []

l1 = getValuesFromListItem(0)
l2 = sorted(l1)
for i in l2:
    my_list2.append(getListItemFromValue(i, 0))

print(my_list2)
```

output-

['i99_W_t10', 'i99_M_t11', 'i94_M_t12', 'i93_W_t2', 'i14_M_t19']

['i14_M_t19', 'i93_W_t2', 'i94_M_t12', 'i99_W_t10', 'i99_M_t11']